# Reading From a .txt File in PHP

Tags: php

I have a txt file set up something like this:

fence
canter1
edger

I currently read from it using file() and what I am trying to do is use the data (eg. canter1) to output a pre-defined div that is stored in an array. So I get canter1 which is in $data and want to output

```
echo $div[$data];
```

I get an undefined index error though I know that they exist because I can go

```
echo $div['fence'];
```

and everything is fine. The only time it doesn't give me an error is for the last line in the text file. In this example 'edger' would be valid. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($div);`?

Comment: i would use either an array or a db rather than a flat file,

Comment: Samy Dindane is correct: use var_dump($div) to see if div[] actually contains the data you expect

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just using `file()` use `file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`.